# Obtener ruta completa de archivo en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, excel, fileupload

tengo un inconveniente en un modulo que estoy programando, necesito hacer una importación de un archivo de Excel a través del control de FileUpload en ASP.NET, y con el metodo que tengo para hacer esa importación, me pide la ruta completa del archivo, pero con los comandos que pongo a continuación, solamente me trae el nombre del archivo o una ruta, pero como si tomara la ruta del proyecto como la ruta origen del archivo cuando no es asi.

```
        string a = Path.GetFullPath(fuData.PostedFile.FileName);
        string b = Path.GetFileName(fuData.PostedFile.FileName);
        string c = Path.GetDirectoryName(fuData.PostedFile.FileName);
        string d = Convert.ToString(Directory.GetParent(fuData.PostedFile.FileName));
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, por favor.

Comment: No entiendo lo que dices

Comment: Para obtener la ruta, el archivo tiene que existir en algún lugar, sospecho que solo lo estás enviando y pues, por eso, solo tienes el nombre del archivo. Primero graba/guarda ese archivo en alguna carpeta y ahí ya tendrías las ruta completa. Una sugerencia, ten cuidado con grabar dos archivos con el mismo nombre. Saludos :D

Answer (score 0):

Haz intentado con Server.MapPath("/UploadedFiles")

[https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.8][1]

Answer (score 0):

Espero te sirva un poquititititito tarde
podrias usar:

```
Dim ruta As String = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/imagenes"), "nombre.jpg")

FileUpload1.SaveAs(ruta);
```

Para obtener la ruta usarias:

```
Dim ruta As String = Server.MapPath("~/imagenes/nombre.jpg")
```

De esta forma en base a una ruta virtual obtienes la fisica

Saludos.

Leandro Tuttini

Blog
Buenos Aires
Argentina